# Razer Nabu iOS Authorisation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to setup a test iOS app to see what I can do with the Razer Nabu but I'm struggling with the patchy documentation. The example for authentication only mentions a 'fitness' scope and with that I don't seem to be able to send a notification to the band (the main thing I'd like to try).

When I try and send a notification I get Operation 36 returned and no notification on the band so I assume that means it failed (return codes from the SDK aren't documented it seems).

Does anyone know if there is a different scope for notifications? I tried 'notification' and 'notifications' but they resulted in failure to authorise in the Nabu Utility app.

Any help or pointers to documentation/samples/guides I might have missed would be very helpful!

NB I managed to get authorised with the 'fitness' scope and read some fitness data so everything's working except for the notifications!

Comment: Looking at the Android documentation there's a Scope.SCOPE_FITNESS in there but no more, so I'd assume that 'fitness' is the only valid scope in iOS too... Doesn't explain why I can't send notifications though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having got in touch with the Razer support guys and talking to this lovely chap called Brandon the issue was that I had the Nabu Utility app from the App Store and the version from the developer site was actually more up to date in this respect, so getting that one installed (and uninstalling the App Store version) made everything work correctly!